# python calculator error using tkinter coolprop

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a calculator using tkinter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhZco.png)

but it doesn't work

I think CoolProp library is a problem but i don't know what to do

What can i do now How can i fix it?

```
import tkinter
from CoolProp.HumidAirProp import HAPropsSI

def click_btn():
    txt1 = input(entry1.get())
    txt2 = input(entry2.get())
    txt3 = HAPropsSI('H','T',txt1 + 273.15,'P',101325,'R',txt2)
    button["text"] = txt3


win = tkinter.Tk()
win.title("엔트리(텍스트 입력 필드) 사용하기")
win.geometry("400x400")

# 첫번째 입력
entry1 = tkinter.Entry(width=30)
entry1.place(x=20, y=20)

# 두번째 입력
entry2 = tkinter.Entry(width=30)
entry2.place(x=20, y=40)

button = tkinter.Button(text="Calculate enthalphy", command=click_btn)
button.place(x=20, y=70)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problems is that `input` waits for user input in the terminal, you should be using `float` instead to convert the text in the textbox to a number for the library.

```py
def click_btn():
    txt1 = float(entry1.get())
    txt2 = float(entry2.get())
    txt3 = HAPropsSI('H','T',txt1 + 273.15,'P',101325,'R',txt2)
    button["text"] = txt3
```